# Removing all alphabets and commas from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a huge list which contains multiple elements which looks like this :

`'A.21,48;B.64,91;C.95,125;D.139,166;E.175,200'`

I want to strip all alphabets and the `; .` characters and append to a list such that the list looks like `['21','48','64','91','95','125','139','166','175','200']`

I tried using :

```
import re
list.append(re.sub("\D","", <the string i am working on>))
```

but it results in a list like this - `[' 21 48   64 91   95 125   139 166   175 200']`

Since im working inside a loop over a very large file a single line of code would be really helpfull.

Thank you

Comment: To clarify, you want to get the numbers individually rather than in one space delimited chunk, correct?  Do you want different sublists for each line of the file?

Comment: Yes, i want each number to be an individual element of the list im appending it into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `re.findall()`:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs='A.21,48;B.64,91;C.95,125;D.139,166;E.175,200'
>>> re.findall(r"\d+",strs)
['21', '48', '64', '91', '95', '125', '139', '166', '175', '200']
```

using `re.sub()`:

```
>>> re.sub(r"[A-Z;,.]"," ",strs).split()
['21', '48', '64', '91', '95', '125', '139', '166', '175', '200']
```

**help(re.findall):**

```
Help on function findall in module re:

findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.

If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a
list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
has more than one group.

Empty matches are included in the result.
```

Comment: @begin.py `\d+` will match all the integers in the string and `re.findall` stores those integers items in a list.

Comment: @begin.py  If you don't want your results to be a series of nested lists, change `list.append` to `list.extend`, but of course don't name the list `list`.

Comment: It is possible that `re.finditer` could be faster.  The `re.sub` solution is a real loser, mimicking with multiple steps what is accomplished with in a single step `re.findall` or `re.finditer`.